# Scrollbar is not showing in Talend

Tags: talend

I've checked all the available options in talend and not found any one,that can help me.
my talend open studio not showing scrollbars. I believe there should be any show/hide option for scrollbars in Talend DI.

Comment: can you brief about which scroll bar are talking about, if you are talking about Talend Designer scroll bar then it will appear only when your component goes beyond viewable area.

Comment: You need to include a lot more information than this and probably screenshots. However, it may just be that you need to reset your perspective. If you go to Window -> Reset Perspective this should solve any UI issues you might be having.

Answer (score 2):

the problem was with my OS,i.e. Ubuntu 12.04 not with Talend DI.
to overcome that problem just disable overlay scroll-bar of Ubuntu.
by using below command:

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars false

and restart your taland DI.
thats it!!